# Bash expand variable containing sed pattern correctly

Tags: bash, sed

I have a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

xx="-e \"s|a|b|g\""
sed -i $xx file
```

But sed breaks with message:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `"'
```

Using `set -x` I can see that the command is being expanded to `sed -i -e '"s|a|b|g"' file`, so I guess the double quotes are why it is not working.

How to fix this?

Comment: How to fix this? Not storing commands in variables. [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: @fedorqui This could be a wise suggestion, but I'm building multiple expressions to pass to sed so it doesn't have to parse a single file a million times, so making them programmatically is my only choice (I think).

Comment: @Svalorzen: If you are allowed to use `eval`, check out my answer below!

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure exactly why you want to do what you're doing but I think that this might help:

```
$ cat file
a a
$ xx=( -e 's|a|b|g' -e 's|b|c|g' )
$ sed "${xx[@]}" file
c c
```

Use an array to store each argument to sed. Use `"${xx[@]}"` to safely expand the array, passing each element as a single argument.

You can build up the array like this:

```
$ xx=()
$ xx+=( -e 's|a| b c |g' )
$ xx+=( -e 's|c| d |g' )
$ sed "${xx[@]}" file
 b  d    b  d
```

Comment: And if I wanted to add one at a time? `#!/bin/bash xx=() xx+=('-e') xx+=('"s|a|b|g"') sed -i "${xx[@]}" file` does not seem to be working, though I think it should be equivalent to yours.

Comment: It'd help if you were more specific about _how_ it doesn't work but you should use `xx+=( 's|a|b|g' )` (lose the double quotes).

Comment: It gives the same error, `sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `"'
`. I didn't specify it since it is easy to reproduce. But shouldn't your solution fail in case in one of the patterns there are spaces? Why does it work?

Comment: @Svalorzen I've edited my answer, hopefully it addresses your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could try expanding the strings using [`eval`](http://ss64.com/bash/eval.html), but it is not often recommended by `bash` aficionados.

```
#!/bin/bash

xx="-e 's|b|a|g'"
eval sed -i "$xx" file
```

You can see it getting expanded when using `eval`, below is the snippet from `set +x`

```
++ xx='-e '\''s|a|b|g'\'''
++ eval sed -i '-e '\''s|a|b|g'\''' file
+++ sed -i -e 's|a|b|g' file
```

To see it in action:-

```
$ cat file
line1/script
alaalaala++
line1/script
line2/script
line3/script
alaalaala--
line1/script

$ ./script.sh ; cat file
line1/script
blbblbblb++
line1/script
line2/script
line3/script
blbblbblb--
line1/script
```

Comment: The problem with suggesting `eval` is that it looks fine for very simple examples, but then people who don't really understand how it works start trying to apply it to much more complicated situations, and it starts to fail (possibly catestrophically). Save `eval` for the problems where there is no other solution.