# error because eval command seems to remove backslashes in stored command

Tags: bash

I want to be able to add newline characters before every occurences of some tokens appearing in some .tex files that I possess, some of those tokens are '\itemQ', '\pagebreakQ'. I created a procedure that ends up creating a command for sed stored in $sedInpt:

```
~$ echo "$sedInpt"
 -e s/\(\\itemQ\)/\n\1/ -e s/\(\\pagebreakQ\)/\n\1/
```

I want to use `"$sedInpt"` as a command for sed:

```
echo "$inputText" | eval "sed ${sedInpt}"
```

but if I do the following as a test:

```
echo 'hello\itemQ' | eval "sed ${sedInpt}"
hello\itemQ
```

you can see there ain't any newline that has been added before `\itemQ`.
So I've tried debugging this way of doing thing by calling `bash -x` to see what's happened in detail:

```
~$ bash -x
~$ echo "hello\itemQ" | eval "sed ${sedInpt}"
+ echo 'hello\itemQ'
+ eval 'sed -e s/\(\\itemQ\)/\n\1/ -e s/\(\\pagebreakQ\)/\n\1/'
++ sed -e 's/(\itemQ)/n1/' -e 's/(\pagebreakQ)/n1/'
hello\itemQ
```

you can see that the backslashes of `\n` and `\1` and even the ones before `(` and `)` that I had placed in `"$sedInpt"` seem to have disappeared when parsed by `eval`. 
So I am bit lost on what to do next to do what I want.. any ideas?

Comment: This could be helpful; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38655622/bash-expand-variable-containing-sed-pattern-correctly/38656093#38656093 not sure if it could be duplicated though.

Comment: @Inian Thank you :)

Comment: If it had helped solve your problem, post the fix you made to solve your problem here and accept it, so that it will be useful for someone in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also just combine them into a single command, which in my opinion is more straightforward:

```
$ cat /tmp/sed.sh
sedInpt='s/\(\\itemQ\)/\n\1/; s/\(\\pagebreakQ\)/\n\1/'
echo "hello\itemQ" | sed "$sedInpt"
$ /tmp/sed.sh
hello
\itemQ
```

**Edit:** As @123 rightly points out, storing commands in variables is dangerous and should be avoided if possible.  If you have complete control over what is stored, it should be safe, but if it comes from any sort of user input, it is a "Command Injection" vulnerability.

Comment: Thank you :) It also seems to handle multiple token on the same line pretty well too, which is nice.

Comment: You're right, added a comment to the answer in an edit.

Comment: @123 I don't think I risk anything doing that knowing that all I do is building "$sedInpt" from already defined strings, I'm just too lazy and careful to type everything that I want to concatenate to them by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Following @Inian advice I managed to achieve what I wanted to do in this way:

```
~$ sedInpt=( -e 's/\(\\itemQ\)/\n\1/' -e 's/\(\\pagebreakQ\)/\n\1/' )
~$ echo "hello\itemQ" | sed "${sedInpt[@]}"
hello
\itemQ
```